# Magento 1.9 - Unistall theme

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, magento-connect-manager

I want to unistall an old theme from my Magento. I read for the moment that is possible only from ftp and delete the current folders. I tried from the Magento Connect Manager but my custom theme does not exist in the list.

Is the only choice to unistall the theme via FTP or is it possible in another way?

Answer (score 0):

IF your theme have feasibility to install from connect manager then you can uninstall it from connect manager .Otherwise you have to install it from FTP or from cpanel file manager.

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

First change your current store theme to rwd theme of magento inside

> system->configuration->design

Then  check your site it should be loaded on magento's rwd theme then remove your theme files from the server using SSH or a ftp connection

[check it out for a reference](https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento/magento_themes.htm)